# when running expres programme get an load error page

Tags: mongodb, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
books =  require('./models/books.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/books');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/api/authors', function (req, res) {
    books.getBooks(function (books,err) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(books);

    });
});
```

Why we cannot use the `function(err, books)` as `function(books, error)`.

I want to know what principle it violates.

Comment: please on your question include what error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of without knowing the error is that you might want to use:

```
let books = mongoose.model ('Books');
```

And your model should be called `Books`.

Is it possible to include the `Error` message and `Model` so we could have some more info about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When query is executed, results are passed as  parameters to callback function. If If there is any error in executing the query, the error is passed as first argument and the results are passed as second parameter to the callback function. And this is how it works.

So, you can't use it interchangeably.

In your case  `books.getBooks(function (books,err) {..` if there is any error `books` will be the one containing in it. And if not, there will be results in `err` params.

And I assume your query is working OK and you are throwing error checking on `err` value that's why you see the error.

May be you are getting confused with the names of the params. Remember, they are just the variable names, results are there according to the position of variables in callback.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on:

> Why we cannot use the `function(err, books)` as `function(books,
>   error)`.

Most `npm` modules follow the *Continuation-passing style(CPS)* design pattern, which uses:

1. `cb(null, data)` to pass on a successful result.
2. `cb(err)` to pass on an error and exit the function.
3. and, the function has only one outcome.

For example:

```
function getBooks(cb) {
    let books, error;
    // .... Perform the operations
    // .... If all goes well store
    // .... the results in books

    if (books) {
        cb(null, result);
    } else {
        error = "There was an error loading books"
        cb(error)
    }
}
```

This is not a complete example, but shows the essence of it.

**TL;DR**: That, my friend, is convention.